# Rescuing a Net::HTTP timeout & Testing with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, rspec

given the following service object:

```
class GetJSON
   def self.call(source)
    uri = URI.parse(source)
    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    return unless res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
    JSON.parse(res.body)
  end
end
```

I am getting some errors when `Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)` takes too long to respond. If this happens, I'd like the method to return nil.

1. Does below look okay?

   ```
   class GetJSON
     def self.call(source)
     uri = URI.parse(source)

     begin
      res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
     rescue Net::ReadTimeout
      return
     end

     return unless res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
     JSON.parse(res.body)
    end
   end
   ```
2. How do I write an RSPEC test for this? (i.e. how can I replicate a timeout?)

Answer (score 1):

You can stub the `get_response` method and cause it to raise an error:

```
allow(Net::HTTP).to_receive(:get_response).and_raise(Net::ReadTimeout)
```

This is described in more detail in the [RSpec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/raising-an-error).

Comment: Thanks. Does my begin/rescue block look okay?